# How to check if a package is installed while installing with make

Tags: dpkg, cmake, locate

Lets say I want to install a package like `kenlm`. I have used [this](https://medium.com/tekraze/install-kenlm-binaries-on-ubuntu-language-model-inference-tool-33507000f33) link to install it and it got installed without raising any error.

1. Now how can I check where in my machine it has been installed?
2. Why when I use `dpkg -L kenlm` it says "this is not installed"?
   But when I use `locate -I KenLM` I can find it in `/usr/local/share/kenlm`?

I know my question is naive since Im new in this era but

3. when we install the packages using `make` and `cmake` whether checking the installation (where those have been installed or those been installed correctly) is different from `pip install`?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: -1: Looks like you jumped past the basic terms "compile", "package", "package manager", and without those fundamentals everything beyond is a senseless muddle. The misuse of basic terms makes this question needlessly confusing for future readers.

Comment: How about you suggest that I need to read those stuff? like I said Im 100% new and even did not know where to start!

Comment: We're not judging you. Kudos for asking the question. The -1 is merely an evaluation of the suitability for future readers. You cannot really be "100% new" if you are using makefiles successfully; those can be strange beasts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `make` or `cmake` you are not installing packages.

You build software from sources. There is no fixed way to "check the installation".

You can look into a Makefile and see what files are supposed to be installed and where.

Comment: thanks so much for the response. even when we use `make install` at the end still not installing package? so just building the software from source code where it sits and how it helps with other projects?

Comment: When you run `make install`, some scripts from Makefile are run. And no, it has nothing to do with "installing a package". The whole point of packages is to avoid all this.

Comment: Ohh I didn't know that, thanks a lottt. Just the last question. lets say my final goal is to install `flashlight` https://github.com/flashlight/flashlight and in its dependencies it says to install (build KenLM). I just need to follow the instruction and build the dependencies and then build the `flashlight`. `Flashlight` just need to know where those dependencies has been built, is this saying correct? And if we have `python binding` it means that its kind of installation?

Comment: so we build `flashlight` and then use the python bindings or they are independent? (I know its kinda different question but appreciate to shed light on this too). Thanks a loot!!

Comment: I am not aware hoe flashlight should be installed.

Comment: @sariii you could consider using [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) to *create* a package - it's available from the universe repository but I'm not sure how actively maintained it is

Comment: I don't care specifically about the flashlight. I just want to learn the logic. When there is instruction to build a package and also there is a python bindings installation, what does that mean @Pilot6

Comment: Please ask a separate question with more details.